# Highcharts animate marker

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I animate a scatter marker when selected through a script?
I was thinking of making it pulse by increasing and decreasing the width.
Could try it manually, but is there a existing function? Didn't get lucky in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can create timer and change the state of point like below.

```
var myPoint;//the point you wan to animate
var hoverState = true;
setInterval(function(){
    myPoint.setState(hoverState?'hover':'');//changing state of point
    hoverState = !hoverState;//toggling state variable
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I edited your code. It basically works, but now after highlighting a few points, the last ones do not stop pulsing..

Comment: Try catch [mouseout](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut) event and then clear all timers.